# Does Bleeding on the 11th Day Join Bleeding on the 12th Day of the Zav Days?

Tags: rambam, niddah, rishonim

According to Rambam in [Hilchot Isurai Biyah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5106n.htm#15):

> רָאָת דָּם בָּעֲשִׂירִי מִיְּמֵי זִיבָתָהּ, וּבָאַחַד עָשָׂר, וּבִשְׁנֵים עָשָׂר--אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁרָאָת בִּשְׁלוֹשָׁה יָמִים זֶה אַחַר זֶה--אֵינָהּ זָבָה גְּדוֹלָה, אֵלָא יָצַאת מִזִּיבוּת קְטַנָּה לְנִדָּה:  שֶׁיּוֹם שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר, מִתְּחִלַּת יְמֵי נִדָּה; וְהָרוֹאָה בִּימֵי נִדָּתָהּ--אֵינָהּ זָבָה, כְּמוֹ שֶׁבֵּאַרְנוּ.
>
> [ If the woman ] Saw blood on the 10th day of the zivah days, and on the 11th day, and on the 12th -- even though she saw three continuous days -- she is not a major zavah, instead she has went out from being a minor zavah to niddah: because the 12th day is the beginning of niddah; and one who sees [ blood ] during niddah days -- she is not a zavah, as we explained.

Since many of Rambam's opinions in the area of niddah are contested, I was wondering what other Rishonim hold on this issue and if there is a general consensus or majority opinion among Rishonim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the Rambam's halacha is really directly from an explicit Gemara, [Niddah 38a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=38&format=pdf). The Gemara gives several examples of how a woman could go a certain number of consecutive days (150, 100, 25) of bleeding and not be a major zava. All of the calculations involve a 9 day sequence of seeing the last 2 days of the 11 interim days, followed by 7 days of niddah, followed by the first 2 of the next 11 interim days. The Gemara has 3 baraisos in which this happens. One example:

> תניא היה ר"מ אומר יש מקשה ק"נ יום ואין זיבה עולה בהן כיצד שנים בלא עת ושבעה נדה ושנים של אחר הנדה
>
> Tanya: Rebbi Meir would say a woman could have *koshi* for 150 days without Ziva coming into them. How? 2 days of "b'lo es" (paraphrase of the verse of zava, the 11 days between niddah cycles), 7 days of niddah, 2 days after niddah ...

There is an Amoraic dispute as to whether or not a woman who sees on days 10 and 11 of the 11 interim days needs *shimur*, the rationale of the opinion (Reish Lakish, Niddah 72b) that says she does not need *shimur* being that she cannot become a major zava through these two days, as they do not join with the following day, the first day of niddah, to make 3 days of zivah. Rashi there is clear that both opinions in that dispute agree that day 10 is not fit to combine to a major zava, the dispute is only if it causes a requirement of *shimur*. [Indeed, the Rambam who rules that days 10 and 11 do not combine to day 12 rules that day 10 still requires *shimur* ([Hilchos Mishkav Umoshav 5:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=59&perek=5&halocha=8)).]

If you want an example of another Rishon who makes this point explicitly, Tosefos Niddah 37b s.v. ורב אדא cites from Rabbeinu Chananel:

> ר"ח פי' דלוי אינו מטהר אלא תשעה ימים הראוין ליעשות בהן זבה אבל י' וי"א דאינם ראויין ליעשות בהן זבה דאפילו ראתה אפי' גם בי"ב אינה אלא נדה
>
> Rabbeinu Chananel explains that Levi only purifies the 9 days during which she could become a [major] zava, but day 10 and 11, which are not able to become a zava on them, as even if she sees also on day 12 she is only a niddah...

Comment: Ok, someone had given me the impression that there was some contention or uncertainty about this issue, but it seems like it's pretty straight forward from what you're saying.